# insert in localhost name with '

Tags: sql, localhost

I want to add a name in localhost with apostrophe like for example i have a coumn labeled company name and the name of the company is `Bob's Bistro` i get error on this how to add this in localhost my code goes like this

```
INSERT INTO  `companyname_tbl` (`comp_name`,parent_id ,`company_code`) 
VALUES
('Bob's Bistro', '1', '140101000'),
('Hilton Hotel', '1', '140101000'),
('Disney Channel', '1', '140101000')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You escape single quotes (`'`) by use of double single quotes (`''`).

You may find that whichever database engine you use will provide a function that will provide this quote conversion problem.

```
INSERT INTO  `companyname_tbl` (`comp_name`,parent_id ,`company_code`) 
VALUES
('Bob''s Bistro', '1', '140101000'),
('Hilton Hotel', '1', '140101000'),
('Disney Channel', '1', '140101000')
```

Comment: can tick answer in 8 minutes :)

Comment: What language and what database engine are you using? I can try and hunt for the function I mentioned.

Comment: im using xammp as for language i dont know what language you mean?

Comment: Localhost just tells me you're using this on your local machine. I believe XAMPP uses MySQL, so you can use these functions for escaping your strings for SQL statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: yes Mysql sir i just ticked the answer because it fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO  `companyname_tbl` (`comp_name`,parent_id ,`company_code`) 
VALUES
('Bob''s Bistro', '1', '140101000'),
('Hilton Hotel', '1', '140101000'),
('Disney Channel', '1', '140101000')
```